# neo4j error messages on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I received the following error messages when I try to run Neo4j on Amazon EC2

Warning: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended.

Error! Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.7.0_45. Please use Java(TM) 7 to run...

Related to the second error, I found a site (http://simonpalmer.com/2013/06/09/upgrading-to-java-7-on-an-amazon-linux-ami/) describing how to upgrade to Java 7, which followed. Yet I am still getting the error.

Any ideas on how to handle these errors?

Comment: Maybe my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565761/neo4j-server-failed-to-start-in-ubuntu-virtual-machine/20571452#20571452) to a similar question can help you.