# docker neo4j cannot connect to load csv from remote url

Tags: bash, neo4j, docker

I'm using the following docker: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tpires/neo4j/

I've started the docker `neo4j` container with:

```
docker run -i -t -d --name neo4j --cap-add=SYS_RESOURCE -p 7474:7474 -p 80:80 tpires/neo4j
```

and in the neo4j interface, I'm trying to load from remote CSV:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "http://mywebsite.com/data/data.csv" AS line
WITH line LIMIT 4
RETURN line
```

And it fails to connect.

So, I attached to the docker container's bash and tried to connect to something:

```
docker-container$ curl "http://mywebsite.com/data/data/csv"
```

and it cannot connect, presumably because requests to the outside are blocked

How do I open it up?

Comment: Are you using boot2docker on OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this issue in the past and it has to do with the way boot2docker resolves hostnames to IP addresses. Follow this thread to understand more: [How to fix Docker's "Error pulling image...too many redirects" failures while pulling images from registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060099/docker-failed-to-pull-images-from-registry)

Follow these steps from that thread to set the boot2docker nameserver to Google's public DNS.

```
osx$ boot2docker up
osx$ boot2docker ssh
docker@boot2docker$ sudo su root
root@boot2docker$ sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
root@boot2docker$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

This will modify the boot2docker VM configuration to resolve to Google's public nameserver. You may need to do this again if you restart your computer. I hope that fixes the problem for you.

Comment: i was using your docker of neo4j, and it dies when i start it up with my own url path for the data. it goes up for 2-5 seconds, then crashes. apparently theres a problem with shared directories in neo4j (see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370043/neo4j-server-in-virtualbox-unable-to-create-rrd-store). I fixed it by using a non-shared directory like `/data/neo4j/myCoolProject:/opt/data` ... fyi

Comment: Thanks Kristian. Neo4j will resolve the issue in 2.2.3. See PR: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4780